# how can i convert xcode project to smartface

Tags: smartface.io

> Is there any way to convert a xcode project to smartface ? I have a xcode project and i want to open it with smartface.

Answer (score 0):

No, `Smartface` has an IDE called `AppStudio` itself. You should construct your UI and application flow with that. From a Smartface app you can navigate to and from your old XCode project.

If you haven't developed much with that project, just switch to Smartface and have links to old XCode project pages. The best way is to fully switch to Smartface. With that way, **debugging and testing** your app will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plug-in support for extend your Smartface project. Its enterprise feature now and will be release to community soon